# Sorting of date-type columns when using Chartwrapper class

Tags: sorting, google-visualization

I am using Google chart to display some data from a Google spreadsheet. This is a segment of my code.

```
var queryurl = <link to the Google spreadsheet>;

function drawVisualization() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(queryurl);

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
}

function handleQueryResponse(response) {

// Prepare the data
var data = response.getDataTable();

var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'chart2',
    'options': {
      'showRowNumber': 'true'
    }
});
}
```

One of the columns actually contains dates, formatted as day/month/year, e.g. 15/10/2013. However, when I try to sort this particular column by clicking on the header, the sorting is carried out by treating each date as a string, so that for example if three of the dates are 01/02/1999, 01/03/1999 and 01/09/1997 then the sorted order (ascending) is 01/02/1999, 01/03/1999 and 01/09/1997 instead of the correct ordering of 01/09/1997, 01/02/1999, 01/03/1999.

My question is: is there any way to ensure the sorting in the context of dates is correct? Do I need to, for example, specify the type of data contained in each column (which was of course done in the original Google spreadsheet)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At a guess, your "dates" are actually strings, not Date objects.  Check the contents of the date column to see if this is the case, eg: add the line `console.dir(data.getValue(0, <date column index>));`, open the page in Firefox or Chrome, and view the developer's console to see what is being output.  If it is a string like "01/02/1999", then you need to convert the strings to Date objects.

Comment: That's what I suspected too but thanks for the tip on how to verify it. So it is the dates of the form 1/1/1997 are treated as strings. Since I imported the table as a single object, how do I change the "type" of a single column?

Comment: You'll have to use a DataView to convert the strings to Dates.  I'll post an answer with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a DataView that converts a string column in the format "MM/dd/yyyy" into a Date column.

```
var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'MM/dd/yyyy'});
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([/* list of column indices that preceed the date column */ {
    type: 'date',
    label: data.getColumnLabel(dateColumnIndex),
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        var dateArr = dt.getValue(row, dateColumnIndex).split('/');
        var year = parseInt(dateArr[2]);
        var month = parseInt(dateArr[0]) - 1; // adjust month to javascript's 0-indexed months
        var day = parseInt(dateArr[1]);
        var date = new Date(year, month, day);
        return {
            v: date,
            f: dateFormatter.formatValue(date)
        };
    }
} /* list of column indices that follow the date column */]);
```

Here's a jsfiddle example you can play with: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/tggnC/